# finding the iterative Schultz method

Tags: python, algorithm, math, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Please help me solve problems with finding the iterative Schultz method. Overflow occurs, but I don't know how to fix it

Gives an error message
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in matmul
B=2*X-X@A@X

```
import numpy as np

def schultz_inverse(A, tolerance=1e-6, max_iterations=100):
    A = A.astype(float) # matrix data type conversion
    n = A.shape[0]
    X = np.eye(n) # initial approximation for X

    for i in range(max_iterations):
        B = 2 * X - X @ A @ X
        if np.allclose(B, X, rtol=tolerance):
            return B
        X = B

    raise Exception("The method did not converge after the maximum number of iterations")

# Usage example
A = np.array([['4', '1'], ['2', '3']])
A_inv = schultz_inverse(A)
print(A_inv)
```

I tried to change float64 to float32 and set fewer iterations and change the error, but it didn't help

at the exit or
[[-inf -inf]
[-inf -inf]]
either an error

Comment: Your code is correct, it seems like you implemented the method wrong. Your makes the inverse go toward [[-inf -inf] [-inf -inf]]

Comment: @lotus, thanks for the answer, can you give some more advice or code how to fix my code so that it is correctly implemented?

Comment: This method doesn't converge for all input matrices. In particular, the matrix `A - I` must have eigenvalue amplitudes less than 1. In your case, these eignevalues are equal to 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not the implementation.

It should be the init of X.

For case A=I, X=I, 2X-X*A*X = I. This is the simplest case that you code works.

For your test case....[image: demo1]

You can see it diverges... quite fast tbh (faster than I expected).

Therefore, I did an effortless change. Which is start with a smaller X.[image: demo2]

For something a little better... I suggest you init X as I/det(A)...
Which is `np.eye(n)/np.linalg.det(A)`;
Or even... as `np.eye(n)/np.sum(A)`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)